# report_timing in Innovus to variable

Tags: tcl

I work with Innovus tool and want to use the report_timing command for write script.
I tried to put all the output from the command in a var without success

```
set a "[report_timing -late -path_group CLK2  -net ]"
```

Is there any solution to do that without write outside file?

Comment: Is `report_timing` a Tcl command or an external program?

Comment: report_timing is internal command of Innovus

Comment: In that case what you are doing should work.  What output or error message do you get?

Comment: If the command insists on writing a file, and there isn't an alternative command to get the information directly, you'll just have to read the file. But we don't know Innovus at all. Do you have a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This is old and maybe you've found the solution but just in case not, the command you want is redirect.

```
redirect
[-help]
[file_or_var_name]
[command]
[-tee]
[-stdin | -append]
[-stdin | -variable]
[-variable]
[-stderr | -stdin]
Redirects the output to a file or variable. You can also directly use redirect characters without explicit use of the redirect command for Innovus commands.
Any Tcl return value from command is returned by redirect. If redirect is used at the prompt, any echoing of the Tcl return at the prompt is not redirected.
You can also use the redirect command to write the contents directly to a gzip compressed file by ending the file name with .gz.'
```

Example for your case:

```
redirect -var CLK2_late_paths "report_timing -late -path_group CLK2  -net"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-collection` option with report timing to assign it to a variable.
Example

```
set rpt_tmg [report_timing -collection -late -path_group CLK2 -net ]
```